# Working with arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

My question should be simple, im working on a program that has an array contains , ID,name,Money. So i separated the arrays to be easier to work with (search, add etc...) But i feel there is a more effect way of doing this, cause if i search im only searching the ids and have to put the array back together each time i find a match. Is there a better way of doing this? thanks for your help. Here is some of my code

```
  // Variables for reading Accounts
   static List<int> importedNumbers = new List<int>();
   static List<string> people = new List<string>();
   static List<decimal> Money = new List<decimal>();
   static  List<string> BorP = new List<string>();

    // Variables for reading Transactions
   static List<int> NumbersTrans = new List<int>();
    static List<decimal> Amount = new List<decimal>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"path";
        ReadTransactions(@"path");       
        ReadAccount(path);       
        Duplicates(); 
        Charges(path);

        Console.WriteLine("Type in ID to search ");
       string id = Console.ReadLine();
       int ID = int.Parse(id);
        Search(importedNumbers, ID);
        Console.ReadLine();           
    }
```

this is my decaration part of the program, is there a better way so i don't have so many arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare a class to hold your data, and use a list of objects of that class.

```
class MyClass // (pick a more appropriate name, I don't know what kind of data you're handling)
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Money { get; set; }
    public string BorP { get; set; }
}

...

List<MyClass> items = new List<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly - these are lists, they're not arrays. If they were arrays, they would be things like `string[]` and `int[]`.

However, you *definitely* shouldn't have all these separate lists. Instead, work out what the relevant types are - it's not really clear from your existing names, but you probably want something like:

- `Account` (with an ID, an accountholder name and a balance)
- `Transaction` (with possibly the source account, the target account, and the amount)

then you can have a `List<Account>` and a `List<Transaction>`. Basically, *one* collection for each logical collection of items. You might want a `Dictionary so that you can look up accounts by ID easily... but I'd at least just start with a list.

Any time you find yourself with two collections which should *always* have the same number of items in, such that `x[0]` and `y[0]` are related, you should at least *consider* whether you might be better off with a single collection of a new type. See [my blog post on this topic](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/) for a longer example.

Next, learn about LINQ - it makes life *much* easier when you're querying data.